# Elementary Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

What does it mean when someone says "find a fundamental set of solutions for the system **y'** $=A$ **y**"?

That is, the system

$$ {\bf{y'}} =A {\bf{y}}. $$

Comment: Note the first quotation mark.

Comment: I've never seen it phrased this way.

Comment: Find a basis for the solution space.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you know the meaning of linear independence of $n$ functions on an interval $I$, we have:

> Any set $y_1,y_2,...,y_n$ of $n$ linearly independent solutions of the homogeneous $n$th-order equation on an interval $I$ is said to be a **fundamental set of solutions** on the interval.

**Edit:** As @Gerry remarked me, note that you are asking about the first order homogenous OE.

Comment: So this is another way to say "find the eigenspace," yes?

Comment: @YosefQian: Why eigenvector? Indeed in that case we woulf search to find vector **K** such that **AK=** $\lambda $ **K**

Comment: Babak, the question is about a first-order equation. You have to relate that to your answer, which concerns an $n$th order equation.